# "man cat" mentions "LFD." What is "LFD?"

Tags: command-line, cat, newlines, terminology

`man cat` says:

```
       -v, --show-nonprinting
              use ^ and M- notation, except for LFD and TAB
```

I checked `info cat`, and it uses the same acronym:

```
‘-v’
‘--show-nonprinting’
     Display control characters except for LFD and TAB using ‘^’
     notation and precede characters that have the high bit set with
     ‘M-’.
```

What does LFD stand for?

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-cat-command/) expands the acronym: "LFD" stands for "line feed." [This SO answer elaborates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12747850/61624):

> A **line feed** means moving one line forward. The code is `\n`.
> A
> **carriage return** means moving the cursor to the beginning of the line. The code is `\r`.
>
> Windows editors often still use the combination of both as `\r\n` in
> text files. Unix uses mostly only the `\n`.
>
> The separation comes from typewriter times, when you turned the wheel
> to move the paper to change the line and moved the carriage to restart
> typing on the beginning of a line. This was two steps.

In context of `cat -v` documentation, it's saying that `\n` characters won't be replaced with `^` or `M-` notation; it'll print as a new line.

Comment: Note also the `cat -E` option will show the end of line as `$` and *also* action the newline `\n`. This is helpful to show up trailing whitespace on lines.